# not print Arraylist

Tags: java, object, collections, arraylist

I have a class where I have a `ArrayList` of `Checkbook` registered

in the same class I have a method

```
imprimirTalonario ()
```

`deveria` which print the record `ArrayList` which I'll be working on that bad

```
public class Talonario
{
    Boleta bol;
    ArrayList registro = new ArrayList();
    UsaBoleta usaboleta;
    public void imprimirTalonario()
    {
         // Convert ArrayList to Object array
        Object[] elements = registro.toArray();

        // Print Object content
        for (int a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) 
        {
            System.out.println(elements[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question? I miss a sentence with a "?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to `add` elements to `ArrayList` By default `ArrayList` is empty

```
    ArrayList<Integer> registro = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    registro.add(10);
```

Comment: my main input data to the array so that it also prints the arraylist

   "public class appBoleta {
        
        public static void main(String args[]){
            
            Boleta b = new Boleta();
            
    
            b.setValorNeto();
            b.setTotalPagar();
            
           Talonario t = new Talonario();
           t.imprimirTalonario();
            
        }
        
        
    }"

Comment: Your `Talonario` class has a `ArrayList` so you need to add your data to this list not any other class list.

Comment: apology takes me a little English, these are the classes that I have   https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B22huY9dy67gb3BsQmRqcjE2MmM/edit

Comment: @Luisruiz Currently I don't have access to Link :( Once I get to home I will check and let you know.

Comment: @Luisruiz I had a look at your code and I can not find any references to `Talonario` nor I find method mentioned here in the question.

Comment: do not know much, but what I need is to print the contents of the arraylist

Answer (score 1):

when `registro` is empty, then so is `elements`, and your `for` loop will not be executed

make a `System.out.println(registro.size())` before the `for` loop to see if `registro` hence `elements` is empty

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any elements in the array, if you debug the code you'll see that the loop is not executing.

If you trying to print the value of type `Object` or concrete type you should override the method `toString` to display the contents of the object data not the references of the object.